# Theory in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was reading through some lecture notes about a theory in propositional calculus. I was wondering if someone could help me understand an ambiguous statement.

"if $\alpha \in Th(A)$ then for any $\beta \in \mathscr{F}^0$, $\alpha \lor \beta$, $\beta \implies \alpha \in Th(A)$."

I think this is saying if $\alpha \in Th(A)$ then for any $\beta \in \mathscr{F}^0$, $(\alpha \lor \beta) \in Th(A)$ and $(\beta \implies \alpha) \in Th(A)$.

Can anyone confirm this, or give the correct interpretation?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what is referred to by the $A$, in your lecture notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is basically right, also if the details depend on the correct interpretation of the symbols.

Usually, in model theory, with $\text {Th}(\mathfrak A)$ we mean the set of all sentences true in the *structure* $\mathfrak A$.

See : Katrin Tent & Martin Ziegler, [A Course in Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=D9sClsdErEsC&pg=PA15), Springer (2012), page 15 :

> $\text {Th}(\mathfrak A) = \{ ϕ \mid \mathfrak A \vDash ϕ \}$.

Thus, we may apply it to the case of propositional logic, assuming that $A$ is a [truth assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)#Mathematical_logic).

Thus, the statement asserts that, if formula $\alpha$ is TRUE in $A$, then also formulas $(\alpha \lor \beta)$ and $(\beta \to \alpha)$ are TRUE in A.

And this is consistent with the truth tables for the two conenctives.

---

*For a different reading of the symbols, see the comments below*.

Comment: In fact, with Th($A$) one _more usually_ means the set of all sentences that follow from (i.e., are a consequence of) the _set of sentences $A$_, that is, the **closure of $A$**. It _is_ true, though, that the set $A_M$ of sentences that are true in a given _model $M$_ is **closed** under consequence.

Comment: This is precisely an instance of the second sense that I mentioned in my comment (namely, theory as a set of sentences true in a given model --- or in a class of models). It is a particular case of the first sense I mentioned (namely, the set of consequences of a given set of formulas). That is why @MatthewRiley had better check, first of all, what is actually denoted by $A$ in the lecture notes that he refers to.

Comment: The relatively _standard_ definition of **theory** in metalogic and in particular the literature on consequence operators is that of a set of sentences closed under consequence (corresponding to what Tarski called "deductive system", in 1930).